# Starting activity which is already running

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to delete one button of an activity but when I start it like:

`Intent inte = new Intent(PasswordConfirmationActivity.this,
                        IndexActivity.class);
                UserAuthentication UA = new UserAuthentication();
                control = UA.UserControl(EdtText.getText().toString());
                inte.putExtra("confirmation", control);
                startActivity(inte);
                finish();`

It gives me error.
The activity is also running when another activity is running.

And that is the code which I delete the buton:

```
Boolean loginControl = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("confirmation",false);
    if (loginControl == true) {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) ButtonClick2.getParent();
        if(null!=layout) 
        layout.removeView(ButtonClick2);
    }
```

this is the loccat :

```
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128): Activity tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421bfcb0 that was originally added here
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421bfcb0 that was originally added here
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:549)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.MainActivity$GetProduts.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:188)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:59)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4591)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4754)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-13 15:37:13.676: E/WindowManager(17128):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 15:37:15.266: D/ActivityThread(17128): handleResumeActivity now pri:0
08-13 15:37:15.266: D/ActivityThread(17128): handleResumeActivity set pri:0
08-13 15:37:17.086: D/AndroidRuntime(17128): Shutting down VM
08-13 15:37:17.086: W/dalvikvm(17128): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b6a318)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tr.com.turkcell.shmobile/tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.IndexActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4754)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:75)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-13 15:37:17.086: E/AndroidRuntime(17128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: `it gives me error.`  What error?  Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Can't it be used something like `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` of this is a view, or just `ButtonClick2.setVisibility(View.GONE);` ? I don't know what ButtonClick2 is actually, so I can give you a more elborate example. Also, do you call `notify()` anywhere?

Comment: i didnt use notifyDataSetChanged() whatexacty it is ? i am pretty new in android

Comment: I meant `notify()` - check this one http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#notify() or http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll().

Comment: i got it but my real problem is to start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

use view.setVisibility(View.Gone); it will remove the button from the screen.

```
    e.g:

    Boolean loginControl = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("confirmation",false);
    if (loginControl) {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) ButtonClick2.getParent();
        toBeRemovedButton.setVisibility(View.Gone);
    }
```

To restart the current activity you can simply finish and recreate it using intent as usual. but remember after recreation, the oncreate() will be called again and the layout will be refreshed including views that you might have removed.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish() an activity, you could draw it new with an extra Bundle for hiding the Button..